# Llamar un valor de la BD a un input

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola buenas tardes quisiera saber como llamo este valor 19  a otra vista en un input que lo pondré hidden , lo necesito para poder calcular la operación automáticamente el valor 19 lo tengo en una tabla llamada Iva

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no tener que poner

```js
 $(".preview-subtotal").text(subtotal);
    var iva = 19;
    var operacion = (subtotal*iva)/100;
    var total = operacion+subtotal;
    $(".preview-operacion").text(operacion);
    $(".preview-total").text(total);
```

Comment: Johan bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. Supongo que el elemento donde se muestra el `19` tiene un `id` o algo así. Mediante ese id recuperas su valor. Pero no se entiende luego **cómo se comunica la página actual con la otra a la que quieres enviar el valor**.

Comment: Si señor , el 19 que se muestra en la captura esta en una tabla llamada iva , esta tabla cuanta con los campos: id , iva , quiero llevarlos a otra vista el valor "19" en un input hidden para hacer la operación en el javascript y no poner var iva=19 si no que esta variable var me capture el name o id del input donde quiero traer el "19".

Comment: Pero en el código HTML ¿esa tabla tiene un ID o algo? ¿Esa tabla siempre tiene una sola fila?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de obtener el valor de un elemento. La más directa y segura es dándolo un `id` a ese elemento en el HTML y luego recuperando su valor en base al id que se le ha dado.

Supongamos que al `td` donde está el IVA le damos el id `tdIVA` de este modo:

```
<td id="tdIVA">19</td>
```

Luego podrás recuperar su valor en una variable mediante:

```
var iva = $("#tdIVA").text();
```

En jQuery, se alcanzan los elementos por su id poniendo el signo de `#` antes del id, por eso: `#tdIVA`. Otra cosa, se usa `text()` porque el `td` no es un elemento que el usuario puede modificar directamente como un `input`, si fuera un `input` sería preferible usar `val()`  en vez de `text()`.

En Javascript puro esto se haría del siguiente modo:

```
var elIVA = document.getElementById("tdIVA");
var valorIVA=elIVA.textContent;  //navegadores modernos
```

O bien:

```
var valorIVA=elIVA.innerText;   //otros navegadores
```

Nótese que primero se crea una referencia al elemento con `document.getElementById` y luego se usa esa referencia. Es una práctica recomendada, aunque también se puede hacer directamente así:

```
var valorIVA=document.getElementById("tdIVA").textContent;
```

El resultado sería el mismo.

Hay otras forma de acceder a los elementos, si no se cuenta con un id. En el caso de no poder modificar tu tabla, puedes acceder al valor de ese `td` de varias formas. Por ejemplo: alcanzando el primer `td` de la primera fila de la tabla `X` (en caso de que la tabla sí tenga id); o, alcanzando el primer `td` de la primera fila de la primera tabla del DOM (en caso de que la tabla no tenga id y haya más de una tabla en tu documento). Si fuera el caso lo comentas y te muestro ejemplos de cómo hacerlo de esta manera.

Aquí un fragmento de código de prueba. Espero te sea de utilidad.

```js
var subtotal = 87 //Valor hipotético;
$(".preview-subtotal").text(subtotal);
var iva = $("#tdIVA").text();
console.log(iva);
var operacion = (subtotal * iva) / 100;
var total = operacion + subtotal;
$(".preview-operacion").text(operacion);
$(".preview-total").text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="tdIVA">19</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>Sub-Total</h4>
<div class="preview-subtotal"></div>
<h4>Total</h4>


<div class="preview-total"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta , me sirvió de guía, gracias.

Comment: @JOHANALEXISMORENOGUISAO Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.